# How to declare a function parameter type as an express app?

Tags: typescript, express, types

I have a node server which uses express, and I need to install metrics on it during setup. So I have something like:

```
const app = express();

installMetrics(app);
```

TypeScript is able to determine the type of `app` fine, as I've installed `@types/express`. But in declaring my function installMetrics, I don't know how to type the parameter `app`. If I try `app: Express`, I get an error: "Cannot use namespace 'Express' as a type". I could create a new type to mock the usage, but that's cumbersome, does not at all seem worth the effort/clutter.

As much as I hate to, it seems like my best option is to just use `any`. I've tried other solutions that I've found here such as `declare type TExpress = typeof import("express")` and it didn't get the correct type (because the import would need to be called to return the correct type). Am I missing something, or is this just a hole I'll have to patch over?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you hover over `app` you can see the inferred type which is `Express`. If you import it from `express` it will work:

```
import express, { Express } from  'express'

const app = express();

installMetrics(app);

function installMetrics(app: Express) {

}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAUwB5iggzugNHA3nAURTUzgF84AzKCEOOAcmVQ3QYFgAoLgYwgDt08AIZgwcALyJirABQBKANxcuwQTGEAbTQFkEMKMB7pZosEpWdKAV348YwAXDVCtu-YeOmxALkIzMeTxLMiA)

Comment: thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for! I didn't realize the type could be imported separately

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a reference to the function that returns the type you're interested in, you can have TypeScript extract its return value and use that to annotate as needed.

```
type App = ReturnType<typeof express>;
```

and

```
const installMetrics = (app: App) => {
  // ...
};
```

Comment: ah okay that also works, although it isn't an ideal solution in this case because I am not importing express in this file

Comment: As long as you're importing it *somewhere* in the app, importing it into this particular file as well really won't make any difference in the compiled code.